# JavaScript solo toma valor de la primera fila

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

tengo una duda y es que no logro resolverla y vengo a ver si alguien me da luces.

El tema es que tengo una tabla y quiero actualizar una etapa con una lista desplegable, la cual cuando hace el evento onchange hace el envió automático del formulario, el problema es que solo funciona cuando lo hago con la primera fila, con las demás filas ya no toma el segundo valor.

el tema esta asi:

en mi tabla tengo esto:

```
echo
'<td>
    <form id="actst" method="post">
                                <select name="estado" class="inpact form-control" >
                                <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
                                 <option value="2" >Opcion 2</option>
                                 <option value="3">Opcion 3</option>
                                 
                                </select>
                <input  name="fexp" class="inpact form-control" value="'.$row['numerodeuser'].'" >
                                
                                </form>

</td>
```

Luego cuando alguien selecciona un elemento de ese menu, lo que yo espero es que me lleve los dos inputs tanto del select como del input, eso lo hago automáticamente con el evento onchange asi:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.inpact').change(function(){
    setTimeout( function () { 
    $('#actst').submit();
    }, 500);
      })
   });

</script>
```

El formulario efectivamente se envía, pero solo recibo el valor del select pero el del input siempre me llega el de la primera fila.

Los datos los recibo así:

```
if(isset($_POST['fexp'])){
                
                $fexp       = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST ["fexp"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                $estado     = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST ["estado"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                
                
                }
```

Si hago en echo de los valores recibidos, siempre llega bien el del select si importar la fila que seleccione de la tabla, pero en el valor del input no importa lo que haga siempre recibo el valor de la primera fila así seleccione el evento en cualquier otra fila.

Entiendo que eso sucede cuando se asocia a un id pero en mi caso lo tengo asociado por clase y ni por esas logro mi propósito.

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien, en la tabla tienes muchas veces el formulario. Si es así cuando dices:

```
$('#actst').submit();
```

Vas a disparar el evento submit del primer elemento con ese id, es decir, el primer formulario, de allí que te llegue el input siempre del primer formulario. Estas asociando el evento onchange a todos los inputs que tienen la clase inpact, perfecto pero luego envías el primer formulario.

Para resolver esto se me ocurre que a cada formulario le coloques dinamicamente un id distinto ejemplo el primero sería "actst-1" el segundo "actst-2", luego utilizar los atributos data de manera que al input de texto le coloques data-form="actst-1", al segundo   data-form="actst-2" dependiendo del form en el que se encuentre el input. Así cuando se ejecute el evento puedes obtener el atributo data-form del mismo y saber cual formulario enviar.

```html
<!-- en el primer formulario (fila 1) -->
<input name="fexp" class="inpact form-control" data-form="actst-1">


<!-- en el segundo formulario (fila 2)-->
<input name="fexp" class="inpact form-control" data-form="actst-2">
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.inpact').change(function(){
      //$(this) hace referencia al input que disparó el evento
      let formId = $(this).data("form");
      setTimeout( function () { 
        $('#'+formId).submit();
      }, 500);
  })
});
```

Acá una prueba que indica en la consola el formualrio a enviar cuando se dispara el evento onchange:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.inpact').change(function(){
      let formId = $(this).data("form");
      setTimeout( function () { 
       console.log("formulario a enviar es: "+formId);
      }, 500);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="fexp" class="inpact form-control" data-form="actst-1">
<input name="fexp" class="inpact form-control" data-form="actst-2">
```